# Ant javac invalid flag -J-Xms<size>

Tags: java, ant, javac

I am trying to do build one of my projects using ant and I am getting following error

```
    [javac] javac: invalid flag: -J-Xms512m
    [javac] Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

And this is what my .xml file looks like

Relevant portion only:

```
   <javac srcdir="MY_SRC_DIR">
            <compilerarg value="-J-Xms512M" />
            <compilerarg value="-J-Xmx512M" />
   </javac>
```

Tried following other options and I still see same error as above

[1] Tried a white space between -J and -Xms

[2] Tried using compilerarg line="-J-Xms512m -J-Xmx512m"

[3] Tried using memoryinitialsize and memorymaximumsize instead of compiler options.

javac -version
javac 1.6.0_51

Tried this on command line and it works fine

```
 javac -J-Xms512m -J-Xmx512m Blah.java
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Tried that too, didn't work either

Comment: Same error

    [javac] javac: invalid flag: -Xms512M

Comment: except now it says an invalid flag -Xms<size>

Comment: -Xmx and -Xms with -J work on command line, so I guess they are arguments for compiler(javac)

Comment: What is the value of your fork attribute for the javac ant task?  I bet it must be set to true for this to have any chance of working because the only way the compiler min/max memory settings could change is if a different JVM is forked to compile.  Looks like default value for fork=false.  Try setting it to true.

Comment: I removed those values, but fork is set to true, I still see that error

Comment: Huh, there is an example of this, in the latest ant docs: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html#bootstrap  Search for "-J"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want the `memoryInitialSize` and `memoryMaximumSize` attributes. See the [Javac Task manual page](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html).

Try with:

```
<javac
  memoryInitialSize="512m"
  memoryMaximumSize="512m"
  fork="true"
  ...>
    <!-- stuff -->
</javac>
```

Comment: Like I mentioned in my question details I already tried this, and I get a similar error javac: invalid flag: -J-Xms512m. 

I guess that is because memoryInitialSize gets mapped to -J-Xms512m

Answer (score -1):

Why are you trying to set heap size limits on the javac compiler? -Xms and -Xmx are arguments for the java runtime `java` and not the java compiler `javac`.